# uglify-js in nodeJS "Cannot find module"

Tags: javascript, node.js, uglifyjs

Here i am creating application to compress a javascript file

Steps i made,

1. Installed nodeJS in my local machine
2. checked node and npm is working
3. Installed "uglify-js" by "npm install uglify-js -g" and installed
4. When i try to run by "node server.js" in command prompt throwing
   error

**Error** :
**Cannot find module 'uglify-js'**

Server.js

```
var UglifyJS = require('uglify-js');
var fs = require('fs');

var result = UglifyJS.minify('site.js', {
    mangle: true,
    compress: {
        sequences: true,
        dead_code: true,
        conditionals: true,
        booleans: true,
        unused: true,
        if_return: true,
        join_vars: true,
        drop_console: true
    }
});

fs.writeFileSync('site.min.js', result.code);
```

Installed 'uglify-js modules' in

```
C:\Users\carunraj\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\uglify-js
```

Server.js in

```
C:\Program Files\nodejs
```

Can any one help?

Comment: Have you tried installing the module in the same folder as your `server.js` file instead? Might make a difference.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You installed uglify *globally*, it won't be "visible" to your package. You want to run `npm install uglify-js` (without the `-g`) inside the directory/package where your script is located.

If you're keeping track of dependencies in a package.json (you should be!), `npm install --save uglify-js` will automatically add it there for you.

Comment: npm install uglify-js (without the -g) inside directory itself.